# Does out of memory error on Jboss produce entry in log file?

Tags: java, jboss, out-of-memory

I'm using Jboss 5.1.1_GA and there is a bug that from time to time Jboss is shutting down without any particular reason. There is a suggestion that it could be OutOfMemoryError. But I don't see anything like OutOfMemory error in Jboss server.log.

So, questions is, does OutOfMemoryError produce any output on Jboss that I can detect to verify that my suggestion is correct and it's OutOfMemory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the stdout and stderr files which the JBoss script also writes along with the normal logs. You can also add a JVM flag to perform a heap dump on OOM, which will help you detect it happening and troubleshoot the issue: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/clopts.html#gbzrr

Comment: UPD: I already had HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError option enabled and have found heep dump file. It's definitely OOM. Thanks again!